# Android Support Library Snackbar with indefinite length

Tags: android, snackbar

I see that the Snackbar will only take either LENGTH_LONG or LENGTH_SHORT when determining the length of its display on screen.

I would like to have it displayed until someone swipes it off the screen. This is for some cases when you have persistent errors, like when you have no internet and you want to notify the user without having it disappearing off the screen after 2750ms when selecting LENGTH_LONG.

Of course I can use setDuration to a ridiculously long milliseconds values, but is there no way to just set it up so that it doesn't disappears until the user dismisses it?

Comment: It's worth to note that the guidelines of Material Design specifically state that Snackbars are transient view elements. Meaning that they should not in any case be stuck on the screen because they block out other elements on the screen.

Comment: Agreed and good point. Do you think the no internet message must be build inside a view on my UI instead? How would one notify a user of "no internet" if snackbars are not the right tools?

Comment: If an active/permanent connection is really important I sometimes change the Toolbar to another color, change an icon or show a notification. If it's just a Recycler/ListView that loads data you should just show the message there (with a refresh button) until it's replaced by another fragment.

Comment: Use snackbar with user input https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/

Answer (score 63):

The latest version of the Android Support Library ([22.2.1](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj)), now includes [`LENGTH_INDEFINITE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#LENGTH_INDEFINITE).

The following will show the Snackbar until it is dismissed or another Snackbar is shown.

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Your Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction("Your Action", null).show();
```

Comment: Works fine in emulator ... but at least on my device (Moto G4 Plus with Android 7.0) the snackbar doesn't get displayed. So it comes down to what @Edward added as comment to the question itself: [material design](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html) does not want this

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE: As mentioned this is now possible with the release of Android support library 22.2.1, use the LENGTH_INDEFINITE flag**

It is not possible to set an indefinite display of a Snackbar when using the official implementation from the Android Design Support library.

While doing this may violate the Material Design philosophy of a Snackbar, there are 3rd party Snackbar implementations that do allow this. Here is an example:

https://github.com/nispok/snackbar

This project allows the following values for duration of display:

```
LENGTH_SHORT: 2s
LENGTH_LONG: 3.5s (default)
LENGTH_INDEFINTE: Indefinite; ideal for persistent errors
```

Beware that this project is no longer being developed due to the release of the official Snackbar implementation.

Comment: It's possible now with support-design 22.2.1 recently released.

Answer (score 2):

I am using **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0** and `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE` works just as it should be. A sample could be like the following:

```
private HashMap<Long, Snackbar> mTokenSnackbarMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

private void dropPoint(@NonNull Location location) {
    final Long token = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    // <submitPoint> is the callback to be executed
    // at a time in the future, if the "cancel" button
    // of the Snackbar isn't clicked until that time.
    Runnable submitPoint = () -> {
        Snackbar bar = mTokenSnackbarMap.get(token);
        if (bar != null) {
            // "cancel" button of the Snackbar wasn't clicked,
            // but our time is up. Dismiss the Snackbar.
            bar.dismiss();
            mTokenSnackbarMap.remove(token);
            Log.i(TAG, "dropPoint: dismiss snackbar");
        }
        mDatabase.add(Point.Factory.create(uid, location));
        Log.i(TAG, "dropPoint: addPoint");
    };

    // The indefinite Snackbar allowing arbitrary cancellation.
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mMainView, R.string.point_pending, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        .setAction(R.string.cancel, (v) -> {
                    mTokenSnackbarMap.remove(token);
                    mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(submitPoint, token);
                    Log.i(TAG, "dropPoint: cancel snackbar");
                });
    mTokenSnackbarMap.put(token, snackbar);
    mUiHandler.postAtTime(submitPoint, token,
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + Constants.POINT_DELAY_MILLIS);
    Log.i(TAG, "dropPoint: postAtTime");
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Documentation, you can use `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` flag while set duration:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "my snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

Comment: How do you plan to dismiss it?   You can't.  You need a reference to snackbar to later dismiss it.

Comment: Of course. But you can do it as simplest way.

Comment: not working now

Answer (score -1):

> Snackbars automatically time out from the screen. They **should not be persistent** or be stacked, as they are above other elements on screen.

Hence, Snackbars seems to be unsuitable for your use case of notifying users until the user does something to dismiss it.

Instead, you should consider using Dialog

> Dialogs always **retain focus until** dismissed or **a required action has been taken**

For more information, please refer to:

[Material Design Guidelines - Snackbars](https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage)

[Material Design Guidelines - Dialogs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html)