# Snackbar Closing even after using LENGTH_INDEFINITE

Tags: android

I am using snackbar to display if internet is not available. But the snackbar closes after a few seconds. I dont understand why this is happening. I want it to be displayed for indefinite period of time.

```
Snackbar
            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Connect to Internet.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    makecall();
                }
            }).show();
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code to understand if there is any issue apart from this snackbar code

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues have been resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185819/10509263) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921663/how-to-prevent-snackbar-from-closing), you may want to check them.

Comment: I have seen them but they don't seem to help my case

Comment: I think it will help if you post more portions of your code